# using <T> in generic delegates?

Tags: c#, generics, delegates

Here is my problem.  Do I need to give a new identifier to each delegate I write of the following delegate type? like so: or could i use one delegate that accounts for any Datatype I need to use so i don't have to keep repeating the code?

Something that may or may not be relevant: I'm calling these functions to prompt user's input for new fields to add for records in a database.  So database field types are the data types I'm dealing with, but I'm using this approach for learning purposes to try and minimize redundancy.

```
public static class stcHelper  // helper class
{
    public delegate T DelReturnType<T>();
    static public DelReturnType<int> UserInt = () =>
    {
        Console.Write("Enter integer: ");
        return int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
    };
    static public DelReturnType<string> UserString = () =>
    {
        Console.Write("Enter string: ");
        return Console.ReadLine();
    };
    static public DelReturnType<AnotherDataType> UserAnotherDataType = () =>
    {
        Console.Write("Enter AnotherDataType: ");
        return SomeKindOfConversionFunction(Console.ReadLine());
    };
    // and so on for what could be 15 other data types ..
}
```

or is there a better way to reduce redundant code?

The code below is also part of the same class.

```
public static class stcHelper
{
    static public T InsistValidInput<T>(DelTypeReturn<T> MyInputAction)
    {
        bool bSuccess = true;
        do
        {
            try
            {
                return MyInputAction();
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Invalid input!" + ex.ToString());
                bSuccess = false;
            }
        } while (!bSuccess);
        return default(T);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 18, accepted):

If done cleverly, you can get away with a single method to get the input of any type:

```
static T GetInput<T>(string message, Converter<string, T> transform)
{
    Console.WriteLine(message);
    return transform(Console.ReadLine());
}
```

All you need to do is pass in a transformation function (the [`Converter<TInput,TOutput>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/kt456a2y.aspx) delegate is equivalent to `Func<T,TResult>`):

```
int parsedInt = GetInput("Type in a number", int.Parse);
float parsedFloat = GetInput("Type in a float", float.Parse);
```

And ta-da, you've got your input, parsed as the desired type.

But as you also noted in the second half of your question, it's dangerous to assume that the input will always be valid. There's a universal version of your insist-on-valid-input function too. However, you should avoid using exceptions for normal control flow. Use the `xxx.TryParse` methods instead.

First, define the following delegate that matches the `TryParse` method defined in all the primitive types:

```
delegate bool TryParse<T>(string input, out T output);
```

Then, you can implement the loop:

```
static T InsistOnValidInput<T>(string message, string errorMessage, TryParse<T> validator)
{
    Console.WriteLine(message);
    T result;
    while (!validator(Console.ReadLine(), out result))
    {
        Console.WriteLine(errorMessage);
    }
    return result;
}
```

And call it:

```
bool parsedBool = InsistOnValidInput<bool>("Type in a bool", "Try again", bool.TryParse);
```

Unfortunately, C# doesn't infer the type parameter of the output argument, so you need to specify it manually (in this case, `<bool>`).

Comment: I am reading your code, and wondering why you have 2 generics inside the 'Func<string, T>' ?  Also, when you call the transform Func, you don't include <>, but include () with a parameter inside it?

Comment: `Func<string,T>` is a .NET delegate describing a method that takes a single argument of type `string` and returns a result of type `T`. `float.Parse` is such a method, so it can be used as a transform. It follows that we can call `transform` with the result of `Console.ReadLine` and it will return `T`. We don't need to explicitly specify type arguments when they can be *inferred* by the compiler. I strongly encourage you to step through the code in the debugger line for line - everything will make sense.

Comment: I see.  by the way, in MSDN Library, it says `public delegate TResult Func<in T, out TResult>(T arg)`. Was your positioning of T for the second parameter `out TResult` instead of for the first parameter `in T` intentional?  If yes, then does that mean that T is determined by the output of the given `Func<in T, out TResult>`?

Comment: the use of `in` and `out` in this case is confusing, but it has nothing to do with input or output parameters; instead, it means that `T` is is *contravariant* (real argument can be *less derived*)  and `TResult` is covariant (real argument can be *more derived*) as described [on msdn](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb549151(v=vs.110).aspx). Be sure to take a look at the *delegates* section of the [covariance and contravariance guide](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd799517.aspx#DelegateVariantTypeParameters) as well.

Comment: I have to stress that **you need to run this code line-by-line** and examine the actual delegates being passed around. Visual Studio is an excellent tool for the job.

Comment: There is actually a more specific delegate for conversion, called [System.Converter<Tinput,Toutput>](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/kt456a2y.aspx).  It is ultimately just a Func<Tin,Tout>, but it is more specific to the task and can be re-used in several framework functions.

Comment: @DanLyons wow, nice! I'll use that instead. There doesn't seem to be a more specific one to match `TryParse` though, right?

Comment: Yeah, it's kinda nice to have.  What's interesting is that there are several other delegates along a similar vein, like Predicate<T> which is Func<T,bool> and Comparison<T>, which is Func<T,T,int>, and EventHandler<T>, which is Action<T>.

Comment: I'll run the code line by line for sure.  But what should I pass for the conversion function when the expected result is to be a string?

Comment: you can pass a Lambda expression such as `string result = GetInput("test", i=>i.Trim());`

Comment: Thanks.  I want to ask about the other part of your answer, you said the following delegate that matches the TryParse defined in all primitives.   Since you have defined it as `delegate bool TryParse<T>(string input, out T output);`  I'm assuming that This TryParse method does not inherit or overload the TryParse method defined in primitives, because it's declared outside the scope of the primitive?  And naming the delegate TryParse is just for convenient understanding of what it accomplishes in the definition?

Comment: You can see a delegate as a reference to a method (a *method pointer*). The name doesn't matter; the signatures have to match.